# How to change random element heights

Tags: javascript, jquery, random, height

Here is my loop:

```
var i=0;
while( i++ < 100) {
  $( "#container" ).append('<li id="li' + i + '" class="item image"></li>');
  var y = Math.floor(Math.random() * 200) + 100;
  $('#li' + i).css({
      height: y,
  });
}
```

This somewhat does what I need it to do. It locates the #container element and puts 100 list items inside of it and gives them random heights no greater than 300.

What I really need it to do is 2 things:

1. I need it to locate the "ul" #container element then locate the "li" elements that are **already** inside and change the ids to id="li1", id="li2", id="li3", etc possibly using attr('id', 'li' + i) and give them a random height.
2. I need them to have an minimum height of 200px.

How can I do this with a loop? I'm still new to jQuery so forgive my ignorance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply check if there are more `li` elements in the list than the current value of `i` and if there are, update the corresponding element instead of creating a new one.

```
var i=0;
while( i++ < 100) {
    if ($('#container > li').length > i - 1) $('#container > li').eq(i - 1).attr('id', 'li' + i);
    else $( "#container" ).append('<li id="li' + i + '" class="item image"></li>');
    var y = Math.floor(Math.random()* 101 + 200); //Always gives an integer between 200 and 300
    $('#li' + i).css({
        height: y,
    });
}
```

Comment: soooo close except it skips the very first "li" element and starts with the second :)